# Adding like facility to my rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a rails blog where we can make post and others can comment on it. Referred this link for it.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project

Now I want to include a like facility for the post. Also the no of likes for a particular post should be displayed. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `acts_as_votable` gem to your application.

To create a table for it simply run

> rails g acts_as_votable:migration
>
> rake db:migrate

To use it in your model like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable

end
```

You will get some inbuilt methods with this gem like

```
@post.liked_by @user1
@post.downvote_from @user2
@post.vote_by :voter => @user3
@post.vote_by :voter => @user4, :vote => 'bad'
@post.vote_by :voter => @user5, :vote => 'like'
```

To get the nummber of likes you can use

```
@post.get_likes.size
```

For further details you should refer the following link.

[acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

Comment: rails g acts_as_votable:migration is taking too long in my terminal. why is it so?

Comment: After adding acts_as_votable in your Gemfile, have you did bundle install ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But after that when i try to run the above command, nothing is happening, the cursor in the terminal keeps on blinking.